# Solving linear system with product of two N by N matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, lu-decomposition

I'm trying to find an efficient way to solve a system of equations given by $STx = b$ where $S, T$ are N by N matrices that have a given LU decomposition for each. I believe the most efficient approach is as follows:

$$P_{S}Tx = P_{S}b $$
$$ L_{S}U_{S}Tx = P_{S}b \text{,  Let  } z = Tx$$
$$ L_{S}U_{S}z = P_{S}b  \text{,  Let  } y = U_{S}z $$
$$L_{S}y = P_{S}b $$

Now $ L_{S}y = P_{S}b $ can be solved, and then $y$ and $z$ can be solved for. After that the linear system $z = Tx$ can be solved. I'm wondering if this is a correct approach (even if its not optimal), its been a while since I've done linear algebra and I'm not sure if I can substitute variables and solve as I did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, rewrite the system as
$$
P_{S}L_{S}U_{S}P_{T}L_{T}U_{T}x=b
$$
where $A=P_{A}L_{A}U_{A}$ is the PLU factorization of a matrix $A$.
It follows that
$$
x=U_{T}^{-1}(L_{T}^{-1}(P_{T}^{\intercal}(U_{S}^{-1}(L_{S}^{-1}(P_{S}^{\intercal}b))))).
$$
In the above, the order of operations is important for computation.
First, note that permutations can be performed in $O(N)$ time.
Moreover, given a lower or upper triangular matrix $A$ and a vector of compatible size $v$, $A^{-1}v$ can be computed inexpensively ($O(N^2)$ FLOPs) using either forward or backward substitution.

Of course, you should **not** materialize the inverses $L^{-1}$ or $U^{-1}$.

Comment: I think I got it, just 2 questions. 1) I'm guessing my initial approach was incorrect then? 2)  In normal LU decomposition the form is LU = PA, if I had that form would I just take the inverse of P to get the form (P^-1)LU = A?  Because P is a permutation matrix, taking the inverse would still be O(N^2) time

Comment: I had a hard time reading your original approach so I just posted an answer instead.

Comment: A permutation matrix can be stored as a vector of integers (e.g., `[5, 3, 4, 1, 2]`) and hence you can "invert" it much more quickly. Regardless, I was just using the convention $PLU=A \iff LU = P^\intercal A$ whereas you use the convention $LU=PA \iff P^\intercal LU = A$.

Comment: Ok thank you. The only part in my original method that I was questioning was if I could substitute z = Tx into STx = b. I know for regular LU factorization it can be done (LUx = b, substitute for Ux = z and solve Lz = b), but I forget if there is any restrictions if S and T are just regular matrices. Do you know if the substitution I did in the original post would be allowed?

Comment: The order of operations in $x = B^{-1} (A^{-1} b)$ is a more terse way of expressing the same thing as the following operations: (1) let $z = Bx$ and solve for $z$ in $Az = b$ and (2) substitue the result into $Bx = z$ and solve for $x$. In particular, step (1) corresponds to $A^{-1} b$ and step (2) corresponds to $B^{-1} z$. Your answer may very well be equivalent to mine.